# Offline Deduplication Software for ZFS

Tags: zfs, truenas, deduplication

I do have a 300TB Freenas server to backup several linux nodes. Backup works with daily snapshot and rsync tasks.

The user often move big datasets (2-5TB) between the server - so often big files are getting backed up several times on several server.

Online Deduplication would be too expensive (1,5TB RAM....), so is there any offline deduplication software out there?

I mean, the files do have the same name and often the same access times - fdupes would recognize them as identical with minimal effort...

Comment: You could always run fdupes, then.

Comment: Does fdupes creates hard links or does it connect the data on block level?

I think I am searching for a tool for the second option (like online deduplication...).

Comment: Those are the same thing.

Comment: No they are not, you cant hard link across file systems where as zfs dedup works at the pool level, so can affect any dataset on the pool where dedup is enabled, be it a mounted dataset or zvol.

Answer (score 0):

Try BorgBackup - but you will have to use it instead of rsync.

Here:
https://www.borgbackup.org/

Comment: I ended up using BackupPC.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use, in this case, zpaq or zpaqfranz

http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html
or
https://github.com/fcorbelli/zpaqfranz

The latter (my fork) have specific functions to "freeze" or "consolidate" zfs' snapshot in a single archive